# Why I always get SIGABRTS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I'm developing in Xcode for iOS, and EVERY APP that I run in the iOS simulator automatically gives me a SIGABRT. All the apps, included the new standard apps of a template, without any coding. The iOS simulator should, in this case, show an empty display, but before of it Xcode gets the SIGABRT! Any idea please? It has happened to anyone apart of me?

Comment: Instead of using iphone 5 simulator try using an older one like iphone/ipad 4.3 simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Xcode install may be corrupt

Make sure you uninstall via `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all`
Clean up all remainder directories (if any).
Download again

I would also recommend install older simulators. There are way too many reasons why and you will see the more apps your make.

Last but not least I suggest running a quick permissions cleanup either using the Disk Utility or a third party like Onyx. I had something similar happen and it ended up being bad permissions on some install files.

Comment: Ok! I have reinstalled XCode and it works fine. All the old apps give me sigabrts yet, but if I do any modification it stops to returns the @#"·! sigabrts. It's done!

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't. Likely your Xcode install is corrupt. Try uninstalling it installing it clean.